# Fill null values based on condition for another column (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, null, fillna

I'm trying to fill in null values in my dataset. The description column has the type of apartment. For Studio, I'm trying to fill in as 0 bedroom while for Rooms I'm trying to fill in as 1 bedroom.

I tried

```
df.loc[df['Description'] == 'Studio', 'Bedrooms'] = df['Bedrooms'].fillna(0)
df.loc[df['Description'] == 'Rooms', 'Bedrooms'] = df['Bedrooms'].fillna(1)
```

but it doesn't work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide a sample of your DataFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without sample DataFrame I had to quess what exactly you wanted, hopefully I was right.

You can use simple lambda function:

```
 # Import pandas, numpy
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np    

# Sample df
    d = {'Desc': ['Studio', 'Rooms', 'Studio', 'Studio', 'Studio', 'Rooms','Rooms','Rooms','Studio', 'Rooms']}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    df['Rooms'] = np.nan

 # Lambda function       
    df['Rooms'] = df.apply(
            lambda row: 0 if row['Desc'] == 'Studio' else 1,
            axis=1
        )
```

Or use list + for loop and add new column to your df.

```
# Import pandas, numpy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample df
d = {'Desc': ['Studio', 'Rooms', 'Studio', 'Studio', 'Studio', 'Rooms','Rooms','Rooms','Studio', 'Rooms']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# Create empty list for bedroom numbers.
bedrooms = []

# Fill the list with 0/1 base on your Studio/Rooms option.
for i in range(0,len(df.index)):
    if df['Desc'].loc[i].lower() == 'studio':
        bedrooms.append(0)
    else:
        bedrooms.append(1)

# Add new column to your DataFrame
df['Rooms'] = np.array(bedrooms)
```

Both ways will show results (0/1) in new column called 'Rooms'.

If I didnt correctly guess your issue, let me know.

Good luck!